# Programming Amiga Kickstart with TL866CS

Tags: eeprom, tl866

I wanted [to burn Kickstart](http://tech.webit.nu/burning-kickstart-roms-for-the-amiga/) 3.1.4 to [AM27C400](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/1PCS-New-AMD-AM27C400-120DC-Encapsulation-DIP-40-UV-EPROM-27C400/274659286006?hash=item3ff2f81bf6:g:mYEAAOSwIy1e8Gtk) using TL866CS programmer, in theory it is [supported](http://autoelectric.cn/minipro/MiniProSupportList.txt), but when looking into list of ICs in MiniPro software I get AM27C4096 @DIP40, apologies for daft question, you can tell I'm noob to electronics, but I bought this chip (prior to checking). is it the same as on the list in software? will it work or I need any adapter board? Using legit Hyperion A500 3.1.4 rom.

[image: MiniPro 6.58]

Comment: https://github.com/mafe72/27c160-tl866-adapter

Comment: @BruceAbbott I bought this one, I believe it is the same one you refer to?
https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Adapter-for-TL866-Minipro-EPROM-Programmer-27C322-27C160-27C800-27C400/184084644102

Comment: Looks the same, so I think it should work. BTW I recently bought two 'AM27C400's from eBay and they are 'fake', just like the ones in your link. Won't be putting them in anything until I figure out what they really are!

Comment: I have identified one of my EPROMS, using the technique described in the AMD datasheet (apply 12V to A9 etc.). The ID code was 98, 8F which is a Toshiba TC574200D https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:4Mbit_EPROM_Toshiba_TC574200D_(1).jpg

Answer (score 3):

Just pulled the datasheets...

[AM27C400](http://radio-hobby.org/uploads/datasheet/156/am27/am27c4096.pdf)

[image]

[AM27C4096](http://radio-hobby.org/uploads/datasheet/156/am27/am27c4096.pdf)

[image]

Quick check reveals they're absolutely not the same, so even if you program it, that won't be compatible with the Amiga.

Don't plug it in either, with the power supply pins in the wrong place the PROM will probably smoke and cause other collateral damage on your board.

Comment: Real 27C400's plug straight in, but his is 'fake' ie. remarked. Who knows what it really is!